# Get name from comma separated column and find its value from another comma separated column

Tags: mysql

I have got a table that has comma separated values in few columns i just need to understand these.
How can i get **James** from column named players

```
1. Ron,David,James,Jermy
```

And then get the number of goals he scored that is stored in another column goals which is **8**

```
2. 3,5,8,2
```

however i could find Jermy using FIND_IN_SET but i could not get the goals he scored.
Thank you very much for your short reply.

Comment: first, go kick the guy who designed this in the shins.

Comment: @Randy: I'm pretty sure the answer to that is "it wasn't me and I have to live with it". Apparently no one whoever designs a system like that actually uses it.

Comment: Haha, That would be me, i should do that but i find complicated things amusing.

Comment: Mom: "Who designed this database?" Jeffy: "Not me!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution like this might work:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      '3,5,8,2',
      ',',
      FIND_IN_SET('James', 'Ron,David,James,Jermy')),
    ',',
    -1)
```

- `FIND_IN_SET` will return 3 because James is at position 3
- the first `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will return `3,5,8` (it will return the substring before the 3rd comma)
- and the second `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will return 8 (it will return the substring after the last comma, because of -1)

but it is usually not a good idea to store comma separated values in a column.

Comment: Thank you but this solution will not work because of -1 as you mentioned as there might be unknown number of stored values.

Comment: @Genus -1 will return the value before the last comma returned by the previous SUBSTRING_INDEX, so if I understand your question correctly it should be fine

Comment: I just couldn't believe it at a first look now i am love with it thank you.